# How to specifically extract files that are in a 7z archive

Tags: linux, 7zip, malware-detection

I have a 7z archive that i downloaded from [practicalsecurityanalytics.com](https://practicalsecurityanalytics.com/pe-malware-machine-learning-dataset/) that contains malware files and benign files of 117GB.
The compressed size of this file is 43.8GB which is large and i do not want to extract the whole archive at once.

Is there a way so that i can specifically extract a few selected files
The selected files are not sequential so that i can't really rely on GUI and select individual files.

| File details | metric |
| --- | --- |
| Samples | 201,549 |
| Legitimate | 86,812 |
| Malicious | 114,737 |
| Compressed Size | 43.8GB |
| Uncompressed Size | 117GB |

There is a csv file called samples.csv that shows which file is malware and which is not and the entropy of the file

The file is encrypted so it asks for a password every time I want to extract something.

I am working in linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way I extracted the specific files is first add all the file names into a text file like this

```
228161
213960
200290
210832
230546
257545
....
```

and wrap the file names around like this by using any method (i used a python script to quickly do it) and save it a file - here f1.txt

```
pe-machine-learning-dataset/samples/228161
pe-machine-learning-dataset/samples/213960
pe-machine-learning-dataset/samples/200290
pe-machine-learning-dataset/samples/210832
pe-machine-learning-dataset/samples/230546
pe-machine-learning-dataset/samples/257545
....
```

and now executing

```
7z e foo.7z -o"path to save the files" $(cat f1.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the 7zip command line options is to extract from an archive but only specific files by name:

1. Install the 7zip program on Linux (eg, on Ubunutu `sudo apt-get install 7zip`)
2. Run `7zz e yourarchive.7z thefileyouwanttoextract -p archivepassword`

You may have to run it via a loop from your CSV if you only want some of the files.

Comment: Sorry to not include that the file is encrypted.

This way of doing is fine but every iteration it asks me to enter the password into the terminal

Comment: I've updated it to include the password option.